# Decomposition of Higgs Potential into Doublet Components

Tags: symmetry, higgs

I am having trouble understanding the following calculation from a textbook on symmetry:

There, the Higgs potential is defined as  $V(\Phi) = -\rho^2 \Phi^{\dagger}\Phi + \lambda (\Phi^{\dagger}\Phi)^2$ with the spin 0 field doublet

$\Phi := \begin{pmatrix}\phi_1\\\phi_2\end{pmatrix}$.

It is further stated that this can be written as follows:

$V(\Phi) = -\rho^2(\phi_1^{\dagger}\phi_1 + \phi_2^{\dagger}\phi_2) + \lambda(\phi_1^{\dagger}\phi_1)^2 + \lambda(\phi_2^{\dagger}\phi_2)^2 
= V_1(\phi_1) + V_2(\phi_2)$.

I tried to do the calculation on my own and ended up with additional terms which look like

$V(\Phi) = -\rho^2(\phi_1^{\dagger}\phi_1 + \phi_2^{\dagger}\phi_2) + \lambda(\phi_1^{\dagger}\phi_1)^2 + \lambda(\phi_2^{\dagger}\phi_2)^2 + \lambda\phi_1^{\dagger}\phi_1\phi_2^{\dagger}\phi_2 + \lambda\phi_2^{\dagger}\phi_2\phi_1^{\dagger}\phi_1$.

Is there any way to better understand these mixing terms or to compensate for them in some way without affecting the SU(2) symmetry? Or have I simply misunderstood the doublet $\Phi$ and made a mistake in my calculations? I'd greatly appreciate help on this.

Comment: Can you tell us the name of the textbook?

Comment: The book is called "Physics from Symmetry" by J. Schwichtenberg

Comment: Page and formula number?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Note that the Higgs is a complex doublet, canonically given by
$$
\Phi(x) = \begin{pmatrix}\phi^{+}(x)\\\phi^{0}(x) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\phi_1 + i\phi_2\\ \phi_3 + i\phi_4 \end{pmatrix}
$$
The potential then becomes
$$
V = -\rho^2\vert{\Phi(x)}\vert^2 + \lambda\vert{\Phi(x)}\vert^4
$$
This doesn't have any cross terms simply because your taking the complex modulus and not just the square.